# SMB protocol supports remote hard links but mount_smbfs(8) doesn't?

Tags: symlink, smb

I've been using the excellent [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) tool on Windows 7 to create *hard links* remotely to files ***on the same mounted volume*** on a Windows Server 2008 R2 drive [**not** symlinks — I included this in the tags for the question as I can't tag it with *hardlinks*!].

I note in LSE's [documentation](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#remotecapabilities) that:

> It is little known, but the SMB networking protocol supports operations to create remote Hardlinks, Junctions and Symbolic Links within SMB mapped network NTFS drives.

On both MacOS Sierra and High Sierra, however, I can't create hard links using `ln(1)` when I mount this volume using Finder.app -> "Connect to server… -> "smb://windows2008r2.example.com/Files"

```
$ mount | grep Files
//damon@windows2008r2.example.com/Files on /Volumes/Files (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by damon)
$ cd /Volumes/Files/
$ ln source_file destination_file
ln: destination_file: Operation not supported
```

So to my questions:

- Is this a limitation of Apple's implementation of `mount_smbfs(8)` or am I doing something wrong?
- If the former, does the SAMBA project's SMB client have the same limitation?